# Binding data source to Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am new to Crystal Reports

Crystal Viewer is showing data table first instead of give data source, and every time need refresh Crystal Viewer.

```
private void crystalReportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnData"].ConnectionString.ToString();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
    string cellno = LoginUser.CellNo;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Get_CustomerByCellNo", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cell", cellno);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    int i = dt.Rows.Count;

    ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
    ConnectionInfo info = new ConnectionInfo();
    info.DatabaseName = "BillingAndAccounts";
    info.UserID = "sa";
    info.Password = "sa123";
    rd.VerifyDatabase();

    rd.Load(@"C:\Users\Abhinavu\Documents\Login\Login\OrderWindow.rpt");

    rd.SetDataSource(dt);
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd; 
}
```

Comment: I have some problems to undestand what you are trying to do. From the code you're setting the connection info for your report to use the query that is on it, and the you try to pass a datasource to the report. What type of datasource did you use to develop the report, OLEDB, ADO.net,...?

Comment: Am using Connection Info Query To the Set Connection From the Data Base to Crystal Viewer.Yes I want Pass Data Source to Reports...                       And Am Using ADO .net....

Comment: Please Solve Problem....

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you want to pass a datase to your report you have to use a typed dataset and use that on your report.

From what I see in this snippet of code I can imagine that you created the report based on a OLEDB and ADO.NET connection ot on a dataset.

```
ConnectionInfo info = new ConnectionInfo();
info.DatabaseName = "BillingAndAccounts";
info.UserID = "sa";
info.Password = "sa123";
rd.VerifyDatabase();
```

Here you have 2 links that will show you how to create a report using ADO.NET Datasets datasource

[Crystal Report with DataSet and DataTable using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28899/Crystal-Report-with-DataSet-and-DataTable-using-C)

[Creating Crystal Reports using C# with Datasets](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12694/Creating-Crystal-Reports-using-C-with-Datasets)